# User is not logged in after login_user()

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I made a very simple user class (I set aside security for now because I want to see how would the simplest implementation work):

```
    class User:
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.__id__ = name
    def is_active():
        return True
    def is_anonymous():
        return False
    def is_authenticated():
        return True
    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id__

Users = {"admin": "ethise"}

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    if(user_id in Users.keys()):
        return User(user_id)
    else:
        return None
```

And my login function works like this (i know that password is supposed to be processed somehow else, it is just a minimal example):

```
@application.route('/do_login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def do_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['pass'] == "qwerty":
            login_user(app.logins.User("admin"))
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

But login_required pages cannot be visited. Why?

Comment: Can you please post the error traceback you get when you visit `login_required` pages

Comment: @Siddhant there is no error, it just says I am not authorised.

Comment: Where have you implemented `user_loader` callback ?

Comment: @Siddhant in the first snippet, bottom function ins the callback.